# Check market is opened/closed for a stock using Yahoo Finance API?

Tags: java, api, kotlin, stock, yahoo-finance

I'm using Yahoo Finance API to get the current data like, bid, ask, price, etc., & also the historical data. But is there a way to find whether market is opened or closed for a stock using the same?

Comment: Maybe the API returns some error when market is closed, try calling the API for a stock product after market hours.

Comment: yep, I have tried, instead it's returning the close value as the current Value!! And that's the whole mess with it!

Comment: Ohh yes, that makes sense actually. Does the same thing happen for pre-market hours? Then one hacky way of checking that is to check whether market is closed is to check if the same price is returned for at least 1 minute. If market is closed, then you will get the same close price.

Comment: Yes I agree with that, and that's actually good to sense open/close in this way!!

Answer (score 0):

Use prepost flag as true in download function and pre market data will show Volume as zero. With these 2 conditions you can retrieve premarket data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).